# My navbar dropdown is not overlaying my header even with position relative and z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position, dropdown, z-index

I'm trying to make a login dropdown from my navbar overlay the header of the page. The navbar and dowdown use ui bootstrap. 
I tried the following:

```
1. #login-dp{
        min-width: 200px;
        padding: 14px 14px 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1000;
    }`
```

2. I tried wraping the ul with that class and setting the wraper position to absolute (that fixed 2 other elements from going bunkers when I click the dropdown)
3. I tried setting the #login-dp to absolute and the wraper to relative

Most of the solutions I found only mention about the position and z-index.

Here is some code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><p class="navbar-text">Already have an account?</p></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="isDropCollapsed = !isDropCollapsed"><b>Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                 <div class="wraper1">
                 <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" uib-collapse="isDropCollapsed">
                    <li>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <!--<p>Login via</p> 
                                <div class="social-buttons">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
                                </div>
                                <p>or</p>-->
                                 <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                                             <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
                                             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                                             <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                             <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"><p>keep me logged-in</p> 
                                             </label>
                                        </div>
                                 </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom text-center">
                                <p>New here?</p>  <a href="#"><b>Join Us</b></a>
                            </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

Hope you can help

Comment: PS: This happens in mobile view when the dropdown is diplayed in the navbar-collapse div.